# How to use filter with *F in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

There is this line in my Makefile:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $(filter %$(*F).cpp, $(SOURCES))
```

Suppose I have 2 cpp file like "docinfo.cpp" and "info.cpp", when g++ build "docinfo.cpp" to "docinfo.o", it works.

```
g++ -I ... -o docinfo.o -c docinfo.cpp
```

But when g++ build "info.cpp" to "info.o", it has an error.

```
g++ -I ... -o info.o -c docinfo.cpp info.cpp
```

How do I make it work?

This is my Makefile:

```
CC        := gcc
RM        := rm -rf

WORKSPACE := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

TARGET    := $(WORKSPACE)test.so

SOURCES   := $(foreach dir,$(WORKSPACE),$(wildcard $(dir)source/*.c))

INCLUDE   := -I$(WORKSPACE)include/

CFLAGS    := $(INCLUDE) -O0 -Wall -fPIC 
#CFLAGS    += -g
#CFLAGS    += -D__DEBUG__

OBJS      := $(notdir $(SOURCES:.c=.o))
OBJ_PATH  := $(WORKSPACE)object/
OBJS_O    := $(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH), $(OBJS))

LIB_PATH  := $(WORKSPACE)lib
LIBS      := -ldl -shared

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJ_PATH) $(LIB_TAG) $(TARGET)

$(OBJ_PATH):
    mkdir -p $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJS_O)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -L$(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS)
    @echo "$@"

$(OBJS_O): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $(filter %$(*F).c,$(SOURCES))

clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS_O) $(OBJ_PATH) $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why don't you just use `$<` rather than trying to filter out something from $(SOURCES)?

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

If, for some weird reason, you do need the filter, then if you don't want to return a match for any value ending with $(*F).cpp, then just don't prefix it with the pattern match character (`%`):

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $(filter $(*F).cpp, $(SOURCES))
```

This is weird, though, because `$(*F)` should expand to `foo.cpp` which means this would resolve to `foo.cpp.cpp`.

So, I think there's something quite unusual (or possibly incorrect) about your makefile... but since you've only provided the recipe and not shown us the entire rule we can't say for sure.

*ETA*

Now that we see your makefile, sure enough it has a problem.  This rule is wrong:

```
$(OBJS_O): $(SOURCES)
        $(CC) ...
```

What does this expand to, once variables are resolved?  Say you have `SOURCES` resolving to `source/foo.c source/bar.c` and `OBJS_O` resolving to `object/foo.o object/bar.o`.  Then the above rule resolves to:

```
object/foo.o object/bar.o: source/foo.c source/bar.c
        $(CC) ...
```

What does make do here?  It doesn't magically do some kind of file-by-file matching of targets to prerequisites.  It interprets this rule as if you'd written this:

```
object/foo.o: source/foo.c source/bar.c
        $(CC) ...
object/bar.o: source/foo.c source/bar.c
        $(CC) ...
```

That is, every object depends on *all* the source files, so if any source file is changed every object is rebuilt.

If you want this to work correctly and put all the object files into a single directory regardless of which source directory they exist in, then you'll have to use `vpath` with a pattern rule, like this:

```
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))

$(OBJ_PATH)%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Now you can use `$<` instead of the `filter` function, because each object file depends on exactly and only its source file, not all the source files.

Comment: I added the entire rule. It works fine when no name contains duplicate source files.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of removing the `%` from your filter function?

Comment: It actually isn't working fine.  It may do something sort of correct, depending on your definition of correct.  For example, if you change any single source file, it will recompile _all_ the source files.  If you're OK with that you might as well just use a shell script as a makefile: the whole point of using make is that it doesn't recompile things that haven't changed.

Comment: Yes, I've tried.And I accept your suggestion to consider redesigning a Makefile that will not be fully recompiled.